# SwiftUI - Controller for view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a new SwiftUI project and added a Text Field and a Button to my view.
How can I read out what the user has typed in the text field and work with if- statements after the button has been pressed?

Current code:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello!").font(.system(size: 32, design: .rounded))
            TextField("Write something..").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Button() {
                Text("Send")
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"You need a binding to store the text entered and then you can read it in your button's action handler.

EDIT: I was asked to use this value to act upon the result.

If you want to display an alert on some condition (or anything other "result"), there are a few ways to do it. The simplest here is to set some `@State` to `true` when your condition is met and have something in `body` respond to that change.

```swift
@State var showTextAlert = false
@State var text: String = ""

var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello!").font(.system(size: 32, design: .rounded))
            TextField("Write something..", text: $text).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Button(action: {
                self.showTextAlert = self.text == "test"
            }) {
                Text("Check If \"Test\"")
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showTextAlert) { .init(title: Text("Text is \"test\"")) }
}
```

If you want to reference something else for validation etc. use an `@ObservableObject` or simply send it to any other references you have. You have the value of the text and you can do any normal operation on it.

Comment: Thanks. How would I connect the stored text with a controller / a separate file? (e.g. to check if the entered text equals to "test" & showing an alert for example.)

Answer (score 1):

`TextField` is require parameter is `placeholder` and `text`.

1. **placeholder** : String
2. **text** : Binding< String >

**NOTE**: also available some other parameter use it when it require

So we have to bind string to text parameter. we can bind variable using `@State`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var textFieldText: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Write something..", text: $textFieldText)
               .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Button(action: {
               // here you can read the value of self.textFieldText
            }) {
               Text("Send")
            }
        }
    }
}
```